# Pandas, for each row getting value of largest column between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to express the following on a pandas data frame, but I don't know how to other than slow manual iteration over all cells.

For context: I have a data frame with two categories of columns, we'll call them the read_columns and the non_read_columns. Given a column name I have a function that can return true or false to tell you which category the column belongs to.

```
Given a specific read column A:
    For each row:
        1. Inspect the read column A to get the value X
        2. Find the read column with the smallest value Y that is greater than X.
            If no read column has a value greater than X, then substitute the largest value
            found in all of the *non*-read columns, call it Z, and skip to step 4.
        3. Find the non-read column with the greatest value between X and Y and call its value Z.
        4. Compute Z - X
```

At the end I hope to have a series of the Z - X values with the same index as the original data frame. **Note that the sort order of column values is not consistent across rows**.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: why the downvotes? seems like a normal programming question rigorously stated...?

Comment: Can you create sample inputs and expected outputs? [How to ask a good Pandas question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/6361531)

Comment: I think what I've stated completely unambiguously describes the problem. The lack of example data may be a good reason to not spend time answering the question if you're someone who otherwise might be interested but I don't see why it merits downvotes. Now the question will just be buried and even if I add data won't get the visibility to actually be answered.

Comment: "What's the best way to do this" is extraordinarily broad and gives anyone answering zero direction. Providing an example and an attempt can give us a starting point to benchmark against.

Comment: @AndrewL the alternative is manual iteration over all cells

Comment: Alternative to...?

Comment: @AndrewL expressing it in a way that is natural in pandas and thus faster than manual iteration. I think this is clear and you're being pedantic for its own sake. "best way" is an idiom.

Comment: Well, I made an attempt to answer it, but I am starting to think, that my answer is invisible. @JosephGarvin, any comments on it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer without looking at the example DF, but you could do the following:

1. Separate your read columns with Y values into a new DF.
2. Transpose this new DF to get the Y values in columns, not in rows.
3. Use built-in vectorized functions on the Series of Y values instead of iterating the rows and columns manually. You could first filter the values greater than X, and then apply min() on the filtered Series.